# Is it valid for %Comspec% to have multiple entries?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I'm working through troubleshooting a problem on my laptop, and I've noticed something odd - my COMSPEC environment variable has two values.

Output from typing SET at a command prompt:

```
ComSpec=%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe
```

Is this valid?

I've found a bunch of references [like this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404706.aspx) that seem to indicate that it should have only one value, but nothing definitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing definitive, but to me it doesn't make sense and I would consider it an error.  The [purpose](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976142.aspx) of the variable was to identity **the** command interpreter. (Emphasis mine). In the event of a user having several command interpreters, I would expect it to identity the default one.

Suppose you did have two entries in your comspec, what would you **want** to happen?

1. The first one is used and the second is ignored. If so, then what
   is the point of the second one?
2. It runs both shells. If so, then the logical consequence of
   this is that each routine is run twice which will certainly cause problems.
3. It runs neither, which is also cause problems.

What I would suspect **would** happen is sometimes 1) and sometimes 3).

Comment: Thanks for the TechNet link - it backs up my belief that this environment variable should identify a single exe. Next step, identify how it got set that way!