# Single quote marks in a batch file don't make the chosen program to be executed

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

When I try to get the output of a command in a batch file by using single quotes I am getting the following info:

> C:>for /f "tokens=2 delims=:." %a in ('chcp') do (echo %a)
>
> 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This command can be run from the same location directly:

> C:>chcp
>
> Active code page: 437

I have already checked env variables and they seem to be set correctly. 
Above problem occurs also when I use 'dir' instead of 'chcp'.

Any ideas what can be the reason and how to fix that?

OS: WIN 10

Comment: Not that it helps, but it works fine for me. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142058/chcp-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or For me, chcp is in c:\windows\system32

Comment: `C:\>where chcp
C:\Windows\System32\chcp.com
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\chcp.com`
Seems like it's in a proper place. I was able to run this command directly from command like with no issues but for some reason it doesn't work from bat file.
Also, my PATH includes C:\Windows\system32

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Can you edit your question to include the complete contents of your batch file?

Comment: Hi Doug. The for loop I pasted in the original question is indeed the content of the batch file. After some search I see that the problem I'm having looks identical to the one described in the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668011/command-line-for-f-fails but unfortunately, provided solutions did not work in my case.

Comment: What if you reduce the batch file down to just "chcp". That'll narrow down the problem to one of not finding `chcp`, thus probably a path issue, or something odd with the `For` construct.

Comment: @DougDeden I have just tried your suggestion and after running the file it returns `Active code page: 437` so it can find the location of the command.

Comment: Hmmm, that points to a problem with the `for /f` portion. So yeah, that lines up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668011/command-line-for-f-fails) question quite well. But you say the ComSpec variable looks good in your case. Ugh. Can you find anything in Process Monitor, as described in one of the comments to the accepted answer to that question?

Comment: ComSpec had this value:  `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`. 
My for loop started working when I removed ComSpec env variable. Then I added it so that it contains only `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` and it still works. And yes, Process Monitor was helpful in identifying that there really was some problem with paths. Thanks!

Comment: That's great news. I've written it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you found, your ComSpec environment variable contained two values: `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`. This causes the `for /f` command to choke when it tries to find out how to find `chcp`.

Changing your ComSpec environment variable to the typical value of `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` will make the `for /` mechanism work.

**You are not alone**:

- According to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/446595/is-it-valid-for-comspec-to-have-multiple-entries), you aren't the only one to get both the System32 and SysWOW64 versions of cmd.exe listed in ComSpec.
- And in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668011/command-line-for-f-fails), a differently malformed ComSpec caused the same "... is not recognized as an internal or external command..." error.